# Calculate the distance for each x and y coordinate

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am writing a function that calculates distance from x and y coordinate. I have a two dimensional array that has bunch of x and y coordinates. 
Function returns a list of x and y coordinates in the order of distance from a point. To calculate the distance from each point there is a formula(Square root of sum of coordinates).

I can calculate the distance for each x and y coordinate. I am adding that to list. How do I store distance as another property as it is for that particular coordinate and then sort it.

```
public static List<List<int>> calculateDistance(int[,] Coordinates)
        {
            List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();
            int bound0 = Coordinates.GetUpperBound(0);
            List<double> distance = new List<double>();

            for (int i = 0;i <= bound0; i++)
            {
                distance.Add(Math.Sqrt(Coordinates[i, 0]) + Coordinates[i,1]));
            }  

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is the question tagged with `java`?

Comment: Something is very wrong here... you show your method returning `List<List<int>>` but in reality are returning it empty since you don't add to the result, just `distance`... What do you mean "how do I store distance as another property"? A property in what, the `Coordinates` array? Either make it an array of size `[n,3]` where it is `[x/y/dist]` for the value, or you should create a `Coordinate` class that has that property...

Comment: If this were a [duck typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) language such as Python you could change the type of the items in the array but C# is a static type language so you will have to create a new data structure and build it based on the current one and the calculated value as you progress.

Comment: I agree with @RonBeyer. I would create a class that stores the coordinates and an operator overload that would return the distance between two different objects. That way you would not have to store a distance because the distance between a and b would be different from the distance between b and c.

Comment: The formula for distance is `distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)`. It comes from the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) which says that for a right triangle a^2 + b^2 = c^2. If you don't actually need the distance, but only need to compare distances, you can omit the square root, since that doesn't change the relative distances.

Comment: @RonBeyer I know I am returning it empty. I am trying to understand if I can do this without creating a class and property. Is there a way to add coordinates into List with their distance and then sort that list based on their distance.

Comment: @LearnAspNet, yes you can add to a List<> but it has to be the same data type. It looks like you want ints and doubles stored in the same List.

Comment: @TerryTyson I understand, that is why I am looking for help. What should I do in this case. Can I use anonymous type for something like this?

Comment: @LearnAspNet, I don't know, I've never tried. For me, it is less confusing to just write my own classes and make them behave how I want instead of trying to get other things to bend to my will.

Comment: @LearnAspNet, yes you can use anonymous type. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description you don't need to create a `calculateDistance` method. Formula to calculate distance can be given with lambda expression. Anywhere in your code you can create the list you need and get it sorted with Linq.

Example

```
var list = Enumerable
                .Range(0, Coordinates.GetLength(0))
                .Select(i => new { X = Coordinates[i, 0], Y = Coordinates[i, 1], D = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Coordinates[i, 0], 2) + Math.Pow(Coordinates[i, 1], 2)) });
```

*`Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Coordinates[i, 0], 2) + Math.Pow(Coordinates[i, 1], 2))` is used here for demonstration. Instead use your own expression to calculate the distance.*

To sort this you can simply use

```
var list2 = list.OrderBy(a => a.D);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you try to define proper data structures for your inputs and your output. It could be something as simple as a tuple, or something more idiomatic like a struct or a class.

```
struct Coordinate {
    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
}
```

Then define a result structure, something like:

```
struct Result {
    public Result(Coordinate coordinate, double distance) {
         Coordinate = coordinate;
         Distance = distance;
    }

    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; }
    public double Distance { get; }
}
```

Then you can create a list of those result items like:

```
public List<Result> ComputeDistances(List<Coordinate> coordinates) {
    List<Result> results = new List<Result>();
    foreach (var coordinate in coordinates) {
        double distance = Math.Sqrt(coordinate.X + coordinate.Y); // *
        results.Add(new Result(coordinate, distance));
    }
    return results;
}
```

(*) Note that the specified distance function is a little bit odd. Normally you would like to sum the squares of the X and Y coordinate

If you like a more functional style, you can change that code quite a bit:

```
public IEnumerable<Result> ComputeDistances(IEnumerable<Coordinate> coordinates) {
    return from coordinate in coordinates
        let distance = Math.Sqrt(coordinate.X + coordinate.Y)
        select new Result(coordinate, distance);
}
```

Changing from List to IEnumerable allows you with the proper care, to delay the execution of the computation.

After you have the sequence of results, the easiest way to sort them is using the OrderBy extension method.

```
public IEnumerable<Result> SortByDistance(IEnumerable<Result> results)
{
    return results.OrderBy(result => result.Distance);
}
```

And then combine all:

```
List<Coordinate> coordinates = .... // get the list of coordinates somehow;
IEnumerable<Result> distances = ComputeDistances(coordinates);
IEnumerable<Result> sortedByDistance = SortByDistance(distances);
// if you want to get back a list, in order to avoid enumerating multiple times
List<Result> results = sortedByDistance.ToList();
```